# Something is using 100% of my CPU and task manager as well as resource hacker are not showing anything

Tags: cpu-usage, resource-monitor

So my (amd ryzen 9 5950x)  CPU usage is 100% according to task manager, (also hwinfo shows max clocks on **effective** frequency and games slow down because of CPU usage -using msi afterburner stats- being at 100% on all cores while GPU drops bellow 10% or something like that.

There are various ways to "fix" this but they are mostly general maintenance things or e.g "reset windows" or "format and re install" I would like to actually **know** what process is taking 100% of my cpu instead of doing "monkey see monkey do" steps and hope the real cause gets killed during this...

Task manager shows 100% CPU usage but only a couple of processes using about 10% or less of the CPU (meaning the sum of all of them still is well bellow 20%)

I tried an other program called resource hacker and run it as administrator it also doesnt show anything, what it shows though is like 90+% of the CPU is used by the idle process but this should be normal right? and shouldnt affect my CPU load.

Last but not least I have 32GB of RAM and about 16GB of it are in use so its not the CPU trying to allocate resources to find space for ram.

I closed all my secondary programs (e.g steam, msi afterburner etc ) but still nothing.

Windows is installed on a 3GB/s 1TB nvme with dram cache and more than half of it's capacity being free space so I doubt the cpu usage is caused by a hard disk issue. (also checked the disk health and did a chkdsk and everything seems fine, manually copying and pasting works fine too)

Network is not in use (at least according to task manager - I will test it with wireshark later on)  just a few kbps  every minute or so.

Is there a way to determine what exactly uses so many resources? (OS is windows 10 enterprise edition)

Comment: Run `wpr.exe -start GeneralProfile` for 1 min while it's happening, then run `wpr.exe -stop C:\cpu.etl`.  Open that file with Windows Performance Analyzer (WPA) which you can get from the Windows Store or from installing Windows Performance Toolkit from the SDK.  Start with CPU sampled view.

Comment: @HelpingHand Thank you sir, I wasnt aware of WPT existence and it helped me solve the issue :P for some reason windows indexer went bananas anyway I got into my control panel and stopped it from searching files and CPU usage dropped down to normal percentages :) But even on WPT indexer showed up using ~5% its only in the graph where it shows (purple) with big chunks and CPU usage close to 200% (?) could you help me get some inference of that? thanks (print screen: https://i.imgur.com/tPXQv2j.png)

Comment: @HelpingHand, perhaps that should be an answer.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Unfortunately as much as I hate to admit it, it is not, I mean I am grateful for that hind it did what I ask for I found what was causing those CPU spikes, but the underlying issue kept existing, for some reason search indexer kept on using 100% of my CPU I tried everything rebuilding it SFC/DISM/offline and online antiviruses/rootkit scanners adwearcleaners and other things I found on the web on that but unfortunately the only real and permanent solution for stopping search indexer to bug out was to reset windows.. :/  because I had either to restart the service or to kill it